# Stop increment and decrement of months at certain months

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently I am showing 6 months in a window (from Nov/2019 to April/2019). A
user can be able to go to the previous/past 12 months (till Nov/2018) and can be able to forward one more month (May/2019). A user can go to previous months and can go to future months but I need to restrict it.

```
  months: any[] = [];
    date = new Date();   
    month = this.date.getMonth();
    year = this.date.getFullYear()

      ngOnInit() {
          this.getMonths(this.year, this.month);
        }

        getMonths(year:number, month:number) {
        this.months = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            this.months.push(new Date(year, month++));

          }

        }

        getNextData() {
         this.month++;
         this.getMonths(this.year, this.month);
        }

        getPreviousData(){
        this.month--;
       this.getMonths(this.year, this.month);

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below can help you. I have rewritten some of your functions and introduced a helper function designed the difference between dates represented in months. (So if two dates are a year apart, this function will return 12).

Then you can compare the two dates based on the difference between them.

I have also added two values, `this.currMonth` and `this.currYear` so that you can adequately compare `this.month` and `this.year` to it's original value. Think of it this way, if you want to check if `this.month` was greater than it was before, you can't check if `this.month > this.month + 1` because obviously `this.month` is not greater than itself plus one. And if you increment it, you're reassigning the value and you will never be able to compare `this.month` to one larger than itself. `this.currMonth` and `this.currYear` are constant, therefore they can always be a good item to compare `this.year` and `this.month` to when you determine whether or not to increment/decrement.

These functions also determine when the year should change. For example, if you go back one month (from January to December) the year needs to be updated from 2019 to 2018. Also, if the month is 0 (January) you cannot decrement it because then you will have -1 which cannot be used as a month for date comparison. You need to change the date to 11. Conversely, if you are incrementing from December to January, you will need to change the `this.year` from 2018 to 2019 and then instead of incrementing `this.month` (which would give you 13-not a valid month) you need to assign it the value of 0.

```js
months: any[] = [];
    date = new Date();
    currMonth = this.date.getMonth();
    month = this.date.getMonth();
    currYear = this.date.getFullYear();
    year = this.date.getFullYear();

      ngOnInit() {
          this.getMonths(this.year, this.month);
        }

        getMonths(year:number, month:number) {
        this.months = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            this.months.push(new Date(year, month++));
          }

        }

        getNextData() {
         var d1 = new Date(this.currYear, this.currMonth)
         var d2 = new Date(this.year , this.month + 1)
         var diff = this.diff_months(d2, d1)
         if (diff <= 1){
           if (this.month === 11){
                 this.month = 0
                 this.year++
           } else {
                 this.month++ 
           }
         }
       }

       getPreviousData(){
          var m = this.month - 1
          var d1 = new Date(this.currYear, this.currMonth)
          if (this.month === 0){
            var d2 = new Date(this.year-1, 11)
          } else {
            var d2 = new Date(this.year, m)
          }
 
          var diff = this.diff_months(d1, d2)
  
          if (diff <= 12){
             if (m < 0){
               this.month = 11
               this.year--
             } else {
               this.month--
             }
         }
      }
      
      diff_months = (dt2, dt1) => {
         var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
         diff /= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4);
         return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
      }
```